# Dismissing an Alert View in different method than what it is in

Tags: iphone, ios, release, uialertview, dismiss

I have an in app purchase in my app and when the purchase is "purchasing", or in progress, I have an alert view come up that says "Loading...". When the purchase was successful, restored, or failed, I'd like to call a method that releases the alert view. The only problem is, I can't try to release the alert view in another method because it will have no idea what alert view I am talking about and will produce an error. Now I have no idea if this is even the best way of trying to accomplish this, so all ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

```
case stateIsPurchasing { //or whatever it's called

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] message and delegate and button stuff here];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a `UIAlertView` in your header as a retained property, synthesized, and released in `dealloc`. Store the alert view that you create in that code snippet using this pointer, and use the declared pointer in your other method. But don't call `[alert release];` when you create the alert view (unless you like EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors!). Oh, if you're adding in-app purchases, watch out for Lodsys...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Haha, I hope Lodsys gets destroyed :)

Comment: Yeah same. Apple needs to attack them (despite the possibility of it breaching their contract). Glad I could help :)

Comment: One more question. I've done everything you said to do (@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *alertViewLoading; in .h file, @synthesize alertViewLoading; in .m file and [alertViewLoading release]; in dealloc, and since a new view controller comes up when the purchase was successful, the loading alert view should be dismissed when the new view comes up. Now, my last question is, how do you say that the alert view coming up is alertViewLoading? I tried UIAlertView *alertViewLoading = [[UIAlertView alloc..., but that doesn't work. What should I do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: As you have already defined alertViewLoading, just do alertViewLoading = [[UIAlertView alloc...

Answer (score 2):

The UIAlertView is definitely not the right control to do this.

You should use the UIProgressView if you are able to display finite progression or UIActivityIndicatorView to show the "spinner".

Comment: Hi Kal. First I wanted to just try doing this with an alert view to see how this works, but I was going to eventually add the spinner into the alert view when I actually release the app.

Comment: If you do want to use the UIAlertView just for a test, you can declare it in your .h file, alloc it inside the init method of your viewcontroller and release it in the dealloc method. If you @synthesize it, you will have access to the variable in other methods.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use an alert view for this. Look for a progress HUD, such as SVProgressHUD, an excellent and beautiful loading view.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/svprogresshud

SVProgressHUD functions as a singleton, so you can show/stop it from *any* class.